# Including a class object inside another class c++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, populate

I am having trouble calling a method on an object created inside another classes private scope.
The error is down the bottom as well. It seems like it is not recognising the Motor variables inside my car class.

Do I need to create them as pointers? Or is there something else I am missing here?

This is to be used in an Arduino project.

Motor.h:

```
    /*
 * Library for turning a motor
 * turns forward reverse and stops
 */
#ifndef Motor_h
#define Motor_h

class Motor {
  private:
    int _fPin;
    int _bPin;
  public:
    Motor();
    void init(int fPin, int bPin);

    void forward();

    void back();

    void brake();
};

#endif
```

Car.h

```
#include "Motor.h"

class Car
{
  private:
    Motor rMotor;
    Motor lMotor;
    float degPerMs = 4.44;

  public:
  
    Car(int forR, int revR, int forL, int revL);

    void forward();

    void reverse();

    //input from -180 to 180
    void turn(int angle);

    void brake();
};
```

Car.cpp;

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

Car::Car(int forR, int revR, int forL, int revL)
{
    rMotor.init(int forR, int revR);
    lMotor.init(int forL, int revL);
};

Car::forward()
{
    rMotor.forward();
    lMotor.forward();
}

Car::reverse()
{
    rMotor.back();
    lMotor.back();
};

Car::turn(int angle)
{

    float onTime = abs(angle) * degPerMs;

    if (angle < 0)
    {
        rMotor.forward();
        lMotor.back();
        delay(onTime);
        rMotor.brake();
        lMotor.brake();
    }
    else
    {
        lMotor.forward();
        rMotor.back();
        delay(onTime);
        rMotor.brake();
        lMotor.brake();
    }
};

Car::brake()
{
    lMotor.brake();
    rMotor.brake();
};
```

errors

```
D:\4. Study\Deakin\2nd Year\Trimester 2\SIT217 - Engineering 1 Robotics Project\2. Project\main\Car.cpp: In constructor 'Car::Car(int, int, int, int)':
Car.cpp:7:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     rMotor.init(int forR, int revR);
                 ^~~
Car.cpp:7:27: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     rMotor.init(int forR, int revR);
                           ^~~
Car.cpp:8:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     lMotor.init(int forL, int revL);
                 ^~~
Car.cpp:8:27: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     lMotor.init(int forL, int revL);
                           ^~~
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

Comment: You don't include type when you call function. `rMotor.init(int forR, int revR);` should be `rMotor.init(forR, revR);`

Comment: Member functions are just like other functions, and you pass arguments them like for any other function (which you seem to know how to do, considering that you call e.g. `abs` and `delay` correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In methods definition like in

```
Car::Car(int forR, int revR, int 
forL, int revL)
{
    rMotor.init(int forR, int revR);
    lMotor.init(int forL, int revL);
};
```

you are *calling* `init`, not *defining* it. So it is wrong specifying the type of the parameters (`int`) and it results in a set of compilation errors.

Just call the methods in this way, just passing to `motor::init` the variables coming from `Car`s constructor:

```
Car::Car(int forR, int revR, int 
forL, int revL)
{
    rMotor.init(forR, revR);
    lMotor.init(forL, revL);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Rookie error coming across to strong typed languages

Answer (score 2):

You must call `rMotor.init()` and `lMotor.init()` without specified type qualifiers `int` in params list:

```
Car::Car(int forR, int revR, int forL, int revL)
{
rMotor.init(forR, revR);
lMotor.init(forL, revL);
};
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. Can't believe i did that . I am use to javascript where nothing is declared.